# Cannot use object key to reference method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, key, array.prototype.map

I have a set of methods for validating input stored in a variable `val` such that I can call them like `val.email` or `val["email"]`. I'm trying to create a general function that will take an object and apply the validation function to each value based on the keys. My attempt is as follows:

```
const validateInput = data => {
  let errors = {};
  const keys = Object.keys(data);
  keys.map(key => {
    const error = val[key](data[key]);
    errors = { ...errors, ...error };
  });
  return errors;
};
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: val[key] is not a function

However, the following executes successfully:

```
const validateInput = data => {
  let errors = {};
  const test = "firstName";
  const errors = {...errors, ...val[test](data[test])};
  return errors;
};
```

When I log keys I get an array of strings and when I log typeof key I also get string, so I don't understand why it will not work within the map function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because some keys exist in `data` that do not exist in `val`

Comment: You're right. I forgot that I was comparing two passwords inside one function. I got it to work, although its not as pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jonas above I was able to figure it out. I'm comparing two fields (password and password2) inside of one function. The following code works:

```
const validateInput = data => {
  let errors = {};
  const keys = Object.keys(val);
  keys.map(key => {
    let error;
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      switch (key) {
        case "password":
          error = val[key](data[key], data[`${key}2`]);
          break;
        default:
          error = val[key](data[key]);
          break;
      }
      errors = { ...errors, ...error };
    }
  });
  return { errors, isValid: isEmpty(errors) };
};
```